# Using PySpark on SVD on 45000x800 matrix

Tags: svd

I am using pySpark to perform SVD on data of large dimensions (45000x800). Is there a way to do this while keeping the data as an RDD? I believe there is a function in mlLib, but it only is available for scala and java.

If not, what would be the best way to do it using numpy?

Comment: You're using a lot of undefined abbreviations, and unless you're certain readers will know what you're referring to, I'd consider being more specific.

Comment: There are several forks of Spark on Github with SVD done in Python/PySpark. Not sure if they are decent though.

Comment: You could use them as a reference to write your own code: https://github.com/Nero-Hu/Bigdata_Project/blob/master/Src/svd.py